# Yocto: provide a custom version of an included file

Tags: yocto

I have a third-party Yocto layer which provides a recipe (let's call it `recipe.bb`) which references a local include file using `require recipe.inc`).

I have then created a custom layer and I would like to "replace" the included file `recipe.inc` with a custom version of it, provided by me. Is it possible? I've already tried to put my own `recipe.inc` in my folder and then using `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"` in my `recipe_%.bbappend` but it does not work and the original `recipe.inc` is still included...

Is there a way for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to override an .inc-file like that.

If you really need to do that, you could just as well copy recipe.bb into your own layer as well. Normally, the .inc file has all the logics, and the .bb-file only has the version specific stuff. Thus, replacing the .inc file would basically be equal to writing a new recipe.

What are you trying to do, that would require changing all the logics?
Are you sure that it's not enough to add a .bbappend file in your own layer, and override a smaller selection of tasks / variables from the .inc-file?

Comment: Ok, thank you: I simply made it overriding the desired settings in my own .bbappend